# Gallery Field in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to implement extra images for my products in a Django webstore.
I want to know if there is any fields,(or alternatively ways) to have an unknown number of images stored under a certain name in Django models

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your product to have multiple images, the best way to do it is by separating the image field to its own table and connecting it to `Product` table using the `ForeignKey` relation.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    # .....

class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
```

This way your product can have multiple images